# Google Apps integration with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

I have a RoR app that other companies use for their Google Apps account. Is there a gem or other way to pull the company's user data, e.g. pull a list of all their employee names and email addresses.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You want the [Admin SDK Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/) and the [Ruby Google API Client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/).